# Does $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k^{-s}\right|-\left|2^{1-s}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}\right|$ diverge, if $1/2<\Re(s)<1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I've been searching for a while now, in several directions, so I end up asking here. My question is: Does $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k^{-s}\right|-\left|2^{1-s}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}\right|$ diverge, if $1/2<\Re(s)<1$?

In my research, it is assumed that both $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k^{-s}\right|$ and $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}\right|$ diverge, and that $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k^{-s}\right|^2-\left|2^{1-s}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}\right|^2$ converges to $0$. We also know that $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k^{-s}-2^{1-s}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}\right|$ converges to $0$ but it may not help that much.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment that got too long.

Note that one has the asymptotic formula $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}=\frac{n^{1-s}}{1-s}+O(n^{-\sigma}), n \ge |t|/(2\pi), s=\sigma+it, \sigma \ge 1/2$ (uniform in $\sigma \ge 1/2$ say); see Titchmarsh.

From this one can easily see $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}k^{-s}\right|-\left|2^{1-s}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}\right|=O(n^{-\sigma}), n \ge t/(2\pi)$

Comment: Hi Conrad, may I ask you to give detail a bit more, and/or to give me some links where I could get info to understand more deeply what you said, because it seems/it's the case you answered.

Comment: this is the easiest of the approximate formulas for RZ in the critical strip and should be in any text on the subject; for example Titchmarsh's bible on the subject has it as Th 4.11 or Ivic's more advanced text has it as Th 1.8

Comment: Thank you very much @Conrad, I have another question if you may, would this formula also allow to say that, if $\frac{1}{2} < \Re(s) <1$,  $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} k^{-s}|^2-|2^{1-s} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{-s}| ^2$ converges to $0$ and that $| \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} k^{-s}| ^2-| \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{-s}| ^2$ diverges to $+\infty$?